# Ubuntu 12.04.3 will automatically update to 12.04.4 and to kernel 3.11?

Tags: kernel, lts

I don't know if Ubuntu 12.04.3 will automatically update,and if the kernel updates too. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point release is just that, a paint release. Ubuntu 12.04.3 is Ubuntu 12.04 with all security updates up to August 2013 and 12.04.4 will have all security updates up to January 2014.

For the kernel and video drivers you will need to upgrade them manually, you can actually already do this.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy
```

If you only wish to upgrade the kernel:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-saucy
```

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thanks,and is it safe to do so? I use that machine for working.

Comment: Can I update kernel from 3.2 to 3.11 like that? New kernel will be faster?

Comment: It does not look like `libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy` and `xserver-xorg-lts-saucy` are available yet.  I just tried updating my system from the raring HWE stack and ran into dependency issues. 12.04.4 is scheduled for February 6th, so maybe this will work on Thursday!

Comment: You will need to remove the -lts-raring packages and then install the -lts-saucy packages.  It worked for me just now.  

`sudo apt-get remove linux-generic-lts-raring xserver-xorg-lts-raring libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-raring`

`sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy`